# Springboot / JPA- Passing Date to controller in REST API - cannot convert PathVariable java.sql.Date to java.sql.Date

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timestamp, db2

I have DB2 table where SOLD_DATE field is a TIMESTAMP type (for example 2017-12-07 08:43:23).

I would like to be able to send URL providing start and end dates URL parameters like below to my controller:

```
http://localhost:8080/irwapi/v1/logs/2014-10-20/2021-10-20
```

My controller looks like:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{startDate}/{endDate}")
public List<CarResponse> getCarsSoldBetween(
    @PathVariable("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate, 
    @PathVariable("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate) {
  List<CarResponse> cars = myRepository.getCarsSoldBetween(startDate, endDate);
  return cars;
}
```

The myRepository has `@Query` method defined like:

```
@Query("select c from CarEntity c where c.carType = 'SPORT' and C.soldDate between  ?1 and ?2") 
List<CarEntity> getCarsSoldBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

When I execute above method, my `@Query` method above throws error:

**"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date] for value '2014-10-20'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Date] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date]"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` above was not working for me is that the `Date` parameter type I was using was `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.utils.Date`.

Once I changed that to correct package, the `@DateTimeFormat` started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options to fix this issue.

1.On controller level which will be applicable to all requests within the controller.

```
@InitBinder     
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){       binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true, 10));    
}
```

Option 2 on field level.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks but note that `@Temporal` can only be applied to `java.util.Date` not to `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` which is what I use.  You can see the types I use from the error message.  Btw, I use these as I am talking to database, so I just tried to map database field types (DB2 databasse with TIMESTAMP field in my case) with my Entity data types.